# Access sqlite from a remote server

Tags: qt, sqlite

I am wondering how i can access an sqlite database that is sitting a remote server.I have read threads discouraging it but i need to do it if its possible.

```
     /*
QUrlOperator xc("http://example.com");
xc.get("testdatabase.db");
*/

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" );

  db.setDatabaseName(xc.get("testdatabase.db"));
  //idea

  if( !db.open() )
  {
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    qFatal( "Failed to connect." );
  }
```

Answer (score 21):

SQLite isn't a network database, so it doesn't have any network connection ability built into it.

You would need to either:

- Make the SQLite DB available on a network-accessible shared drive OR
- Write/find an existing network server/web service for it

A web application is essentially a web service. If you happen to be running a web application on top of this DB, just expose certain levels of DB access to admins-only.

It's not recommended you do this because multiple threads/clients/etc. accessing a SQLite DB simultaneously may lead to concurrency problems very quickly.

Answer (score 20):

While sqlite itself does not provide any network endpoints you can use a web gui such as [sqlite-web](https://github.com/coleifer/sqlite-web).

Assuming you have python installed you can install it with

```bash
pip install sqlite-web
```

Once installed, start the web interface with:

```
sqlite_web my_database.db
```

By default it runs on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ ie is only accesible from the localhost.

To make it visible on your LAN/WAN start it with:

```
sqlite_web --host 0.0.0.0 my_database.db
```

While running with `--host 0.0.0.0` might be fine on your own home or corporate network, it's a really bad idea to do it on a public host (even though the app allows setting a password). For remote access on a public host you will probably want to use the default binding on `127.0.0.1` and then forward the port over ssh or a vpn tunnel.

The UI has an option to export CSV or JSON and if you look at the request being made in the browser devtools you'll see that you can get the data directly as JSON by doing a POST request with an SQL query (*very neat for playing and debugging in your intranet but ***worst nightmare*** ever if you expose that over the internet ❗️ ❌ — you have been warned❗️*):

##### Example POST request to get JSON data

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/mytable/query/ --data-raw 'sql=SELECT * FROM mytable limit 42;&export_json='
```

##### Final considerations

> ❗️ It depends on your use case but probably the best answer to the original question is *"don't do it!"* If you need to access the data programmatically over the net then export the sqlite tables to something like JSON files and put them on a webserver, or expose the database via a more secure mechanisms like e.g. [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (django rest framework), [flask restfull](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [google firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), etc.

<sup>Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the author of the app. Just had the same need as the op and found the app on github.</sup>

Answer (score 8):

SQLite is file-based only. There is no way to talk to it over TCP/IP.

Like an Access database file, you have to have the database file in a network shared folder. The path is usually going to be a UNC path, like "\server\sharename\folderpath\databasefile".

The problem is the connection string you built isn't a connection string. It's a partial string. You have this:

```
DataSource = @"\\\\" + txtipaddress.Text + @"\qscanDBAttacheds\test.s3db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"
```

The "DataSource" part has to be part of the string you build. You don't have that. You need this:

```
string connString = @"Data Source=\\" + txtipaddress.Text + @"\qscanDBAttacheds\test.s3db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;"
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly access an sqlite database remotely like that. If you need to share it, you will have to develop a web service and talk to the web service rather than the database from your Qt Application.

There are some tools which act as a web service for stuff like that, e.g. [this site](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork) has some links.

Answer (score 3):

you can consider switching to PostgreSQL instead of SQLite, the database manipulation is very similar. The little differences in handling primary keys etc you can google. For example in the INSERT statement you'd pass a NULL in SQLite, as a primary key and in Postgre you'd pass it as DEFAULT (given you want the database to create the key for you).

In Python3 for example, the code difference I know of is that PostgreSQL allows remote connection and that avoiding SQL injection syntax is slightly different, as SQLite3 way would be with `?` and PostgreSQL9.5 would be with `%s`

Switching to Postgre would provide you a remote connection possibility and it is a definite step up from using a local database (which is only designed for small to medium bandwidth applications).

Answer (score 2):

sqlite is a document database meaning that its pretty much just a flat file store of your data with only the most minimal database engine on top, that is why it is like 300kb total. What you can do as a solution is to copy the db from your remote location to your location via ftp or access it by assigning a network share location to it. Be warned though that only 1 user can write to sqlite at a time.

Comment: "Document database" in this case is not to be confused with No-SQL databases such as MongoDB, etc. SQLite is a relational database. I think what is meant here is that the SQLite data is stored in a single file, and there's no extra database server running on top of it to make it accessible, therefore simply copying a file from one place to another is sufficient to move AND make the database accessible on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php on the server to run whatever sql commands you need and just navigate to the php page from the device.