# Is it possible to connect a sqlite3 database remotly

Tags: php, sqlite

Is it possible to connect a sqlite3 database from one server to another. Just like what we are using mysql_connect function ?. If so how can I connect. please help

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357496/access-sqlite-from-a-remote-server .  Short answer: yes, but probably not how you'd want to do it.

Comment: @DaveS. I just need to replicate data into  another server which has sqlite3 db

Comment: Then why not ask that question instead of the one you asked?  It's better to ask how to do what you want, not if one possible solution will work.

Comment: It is technically possible to use an sqlite3 database over NFS. The performance will suck and some features (anything that requires locking and especially WAL) will not work.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is an *embedded* database; there is no such thing as an SQLite server.

SQLite is file-based, so you can connect to any database file that you can access on a file server.

Please note that many network file systems are not capable of correct locking, so [this might corrupt your database](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html).