# can't connect to .db sqlite php

Tags: php, wordpress, sqlite

I am trying to use sqlite PDO. In order to open `.db` file I try:

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlite:http://domain.com/path/to/db.db");
```

My website is made with wordpress custom theme. My `.db` file is sqlite v3 format. But I am still getting error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

I can't figure out what to do.

Comment: File path, not URL

Comment: Oh my god kill me please. Thanks a lot ! Love you.

Comment: But now another problem occurred. What if that .db file is in completely another ftp server which I have full control of?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357696/3885509

Comment: Love You again ! <333