# How to connect to SQLite database with Node-Js?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I'm trying to connect to SQLite database with Node-Js, I can connect but with the database locally using the code below

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
var db = new sqlite3.Database('prueba1');
```

I want to know if there is any way to connect to a database host in other server, not in my local project. Thanks.

Comment: A sqlite database is a file. If you want to use a database on another server, use a database server like postgresql, mariadb, firebird, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access sqlite from a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357496/access-sqlite-from-a-remote-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql',
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
});
use sequelize orm....
```

Comment: Sequelize is greate but u can just use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite