# Is there a way to connect to sqlite3 database via python socket?

Tags: python, sqlite, sockets

I'm trying to write a socket client program in Python that can request the following information from a server: school fees for the term of a particular student, the balance(if part of the fees has been paid) and the client must request an option to pay the fees. 
I need to create the students database and login system.

Comment: If you have a client / server system that is use by multiple users SQlite is not the way to go. Check out one of the typical Open Source database servers: PostgresQL, MySQL, MariaDB...

Answer (score 0):

SQLite3 cannot be used remotely.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357696/13564014