# Connection to the sqlite database from another machine

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I have set up a `sqlite3` database on Raspberry Pi - Raspberry Pi is connected to the local network.

> I want to connect to this database - and then I will create a Flask API on my computer - locally.

> How do I connect to this database that I have set up on Raspberry Pi? Can I do it with Paramiko for example?

> I've read a bit about it, but I haven't found any clear answer that is possible at all.

> I would also like to have access to some GUI - to have direct access to Raspberry Pi where sqlite works - I checked some public GUI for sqlite browsing - but it works only locally (it can't be connected to another machine)

I'm asking for some information, possibly some tips on how I can connect to this database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access sqlite from a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357496/access-sqlite-from-a-remote-server)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt well, all of these things are similar - there is no clear answer. I was thinking about putting sqlite3 on my computer, connect somehow with raspberry pi and give a link to the raspberry database. A database file placed on raspberry pi will be considered as a database on my computer - does it make any sense and can it work like that at all?