# How to connect to SQLite database on remote server in R using SSH?

Tags: r, database, sqlite, ssh

I have experience using R but am new to working with a remote server. Using SSH I need to connect to a remote server and access an SQLite database in R.

I can establish the SSH connection using openSSH in the command line using

```
ssh root@ip-address
```

My key is stored on the server and in my /.ssh directory, it prompts my password for my key, and works fine.

Now I want to connect to the SQLite database thats in a directory on the server in R. My understanding is that the following is the basic code

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

connection <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = directory/database-name)
```

but in my case the directory is located on the server. How can I tell R to locate the database on the remote server?

Probably a really basic question, but thanks for any help!

Comment: What OS are you using? What you are describing doesn't seem possible over traditional SSH. You'd need to use something that would mount the remote directory as a local directory on your machine that you can access. More discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357496/access-sqlite-from-a-remote-server

Comment: I am using Windows.

Hm, I see. Thanks a lot for the link, so I guess I am stuck with a local copy, mounting the directory, or asking if a different database system can be used.