# how to connect sqlite which is attached as volume in docker

Tags: docker, sqlite, ubuntu, robotframework

I am trying to find what is the sqlite database URL for me to run automation testing.

There is one `sqllite database` at my local path.

I did not see sql server docker, below is the only place I saw the database is being attached as volume.

Is this common practise that all services running as docker container but database is sitting local then attach to docker?

In this case how do I know the port in order to make use `DatabaseLibrary` to connect?

```
  api:
    image: test/api/server:${TEST_VERSION}
    container_name: test_api_server
    privileged: true
    shm_size: 1gb
    ports:
      - ${API_SERVER_PORT}:${API_SERVER_PORT}
    environment:
      - DB_WATCHER_ADDR=http://watcher:${DB_WATCHER_API_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ${DB_DIR}:/home/test/api_server/db
```

Comment: [SQLite](https://sqlite.org) doesn't have a separate server; the database proper is embedded in the application and all of the database state is in a single file.  There is no port number, and the file path you need depends on how the filesystem is laid out in the Dockerfile.

Comment: At host, i tried using this pip install sqlite-web. And attach db file, i can see db content from web at host machine chrome. Follow  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357496/access-sqlite-from-a-remote-server ,  i set 0.0.0.0 but at anothwr machine by using host machine ip:8080, i cannot see the db content.